# AIR plugins are missing

Tags: air, plugins, pro-tools

I just updated to PT 10.1.2 and now all my AIR plugins are gone. Has this happened to anyone? And how I can get them back? Many thanks!

Comment: just checked mine and they all seem working after the update. Ive got MBP with latest Lion. Did you check any updates for the plugins?

Answer (score 1):

10.1.3 has been released as there were complaints of some major bugs with 10.1.2. Try downloading and installing that instead.

When you're installing there is a screen with the option to choose what elements to install. There's an option for the plug-ins, so make sure it's ticked.